# Rails 3 - Help me setup an AJAX Search Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Could use some help setting up an AJAX Search form for Users...

**config.rb - controller:**

```
resources :users, :only => [:index, :show, :searchresult] do
  collection do
      get 'searchresult'
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

**Controller:**

```
  def searchresult
     @users = User.search(params[:name])    
  end
```

**View:**

```
<% form_tag users_searchresult_path, :method => 'get' do %>
```

Right now I'm getting the following **error**: 
undefined local variable or method `users_searchresult_path' for #<#:0x1092ecdb8>

What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: <% form_tag @users, :URL => users_searchresult_path ..  ?

Comment: hmm, no luck... I think something with the routes are wrong. What do you think about the config.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `rake routes` from your application directory. I think you'll find that the correct path is actually `searchresult_users_path`.

As a way of explanation: Rails prepends the action, not appends. Think how `users#new` becomes `new_user_path` and `users#edit` becomes `edit_user_path`. Same with this; `users#searchresult` becomes `searchresult_users_path`.

Sidenote: `rake routes` is one handy tool for looking things like this up. I know it's certainly made my life easier.